# How to refactor correctly and effectively

Tags: xcode, refactoring

How to refactor effectively

I tried cleaning the code to ensure that it’s more readable which didn’t work out the way I intended it to

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the code you are refactoring is under test. Run the tests after each refactoring step.

Commit your refactored code to version control regularly - as soon as you find it hard to remember all you recent refactorings. The code repository is has a better memory than you do!

Use a good IDE (e.g. Eclipse, Intellij, VSCode) and as far as possible use its wizards to do the refactoring for you, e.g. renaming variables, making a method static, etc. It won't make mistakes!

If you have to make a more complicated change, that the IDE does not support (e.g. strength reduction of a loop) then first think carefully about whether the test coverage is adequate - tests that cover the original code might not cover your refactored code. If so, first add and commit the extra tests.